# jQuery .live('click') seems to only bind to the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a bunch of buttons on a page, interspersed with other HTML, that look like this:

```
<input class="add_new_task" type="submit" value="Add New Task">
<input class="add_new_task" type="submit" value="Add New Task">
<input class="add_new_task" type="submit" value="Add New Task">
```

And then I have my selector as follows:

```
$JQ('.add_new_task').live('click', function(){
    //do some stuff
});
```

However, the live('click') only seems to bind to the first element, and so nothing will happen with the 2nd, 3rd etc. elements. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing

EDIT:

Turns out I was being stupid - I added some error checking to not allow submission if a text box was empty - but I was targetting the text box (stupidly) by id, and that in turn was selecting the first textbox with that ID - which indeed was empty. Changed to a class based selection system for these now - thanks for all the answers though!

Comment: hmmm... `live` should work, despite the fact that it's deprecated. Try using `on` instead, and be sure to wrap your jquery in `$JQ(function(){...})`

Comment: Seems to work ok, http://jsfiddle.net/jhfR4/

Comment: Likewise, Biff MaGriff - your jsfiddle works correctly for me in Chrome and FF. OP, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on the jQuery API site

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Try using the .on() method other than that it all looks fine to me

Answer (score 1):

Use .on() if this is jQuery 1.7+

http://api.jquery.com/on/

EDIT: Also, depending on what you are doing, .on() may not be necessary. Try .click()...

```
$JQ('.add_new_task').click(function(){
  //do some stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this - although I'm using 1.6.2, and everything is generated by JS, so I need to use live(), or on()

Comment: If you are using 1.6.2 go ahead and use live(), if needed. Otherwise just use .click() :)

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should be using .on , because on replaces all event binding as of 1.7, but you might be using a lower version off course.
When you are using live, you want to be using event delegation, this means you have to bind to a parent object which will then handle specific propagated events from (specific) child elements.

wrap your input fields in a div like this

```
<div id="tasks">
    <input class="add_new_task" type="submit" value="Add New Task">
    <input class="add_new_task" type="submit" value="Add New Task">
    <input class="add_new_task" type="submit" value="Add New Task">
</div>
```

with .live this should work:

```
$JQ('#tasks').live('click', function(){
    //do some stuff
});
```

Better off course would be to use .on like this ( same html )

```
$("#tasks").on("click", ".add_new_task", function(event){
    //do some stuff
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm using live() because I started the project when 1.6.2 was the latest version - might upgrade to on() at _some_ point in the future though